# How to display number notification next to a single menu item

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a route that conditionally displays menu items based on your permissions.

I want to display the notification for emails next to one of these routes, however they just repeat the same `<li>` so how would I do this exactly?

[screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/ZRYvP6cV/Screen-Shot-2019-10-14-at-12-05-01-PM.png)

Tried a few different *ngIf statements but no luck just displays on every item.

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let link of wcsdata.col4.links">
  <li *ngIf="checkUserPermissions(link.userPermissions) && checkIfGroupSelectionIsRequired(link.groupMustBeSelected) && checkIfSpecificGroup(link.displayText)">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" [attr.data-analytics]="link.analytics? link.analytics:null" (click)="handleNavigation(link.route)"> {{link.displayText}}</a> <span class="fa-stack fa-lg message-center"> <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i> <i class="fa-stack-1x text-primary fa-inverse">3</i> </span></li>
</ng-container>
```

typescript

```
  checkIfSpecificGroup(displayText) {
    if (displayText === 'Message Center') {
      if (this.userCacheService.getUserData('messageCenterEnabled')) {
        return true;
      } else { return false; }

    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

I want the message-center stacked icons to only display next ot the message-center route when visible.

Comment: looks like you're returning true even if the displayText is not equal to Message Center...is this correct?

Comment: Correct.  This is a multi person project I am not officially an angular dev, just a FED who does more html/css.

To me it seems like I need to add the html to the `messageCenterEnabled` part to get to only display there?

Comment: I think the dev who put this part in just did this as a failsafe.

Comment: To me it seems like if displayText doesn't equal "Message Center" it should return false and not true?

Comment: Also can clean it up a little to make it a bit more readable

Comment: I think we're focusing on the wrong part here.

I am trying to find a way to display a icon on just message center not have it repeat on each `<li>`.